# the centroid-based clustering is NP-hard

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-optimization, computational-complexity, clustering

I am trying to understand why the centroid-based clustering is NP-hard.

Assume we have one-dimensional sorted data set $x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}$ and we want to find, say $k$, optimal clusters (intervals) $\mathcal{X}_{1},\dots,\mathcal{X}_{k}$ is a sense of sum of $l_{2}$-distances to the corresponding centroids.

Since we can not solve it in a polinomial time, then, I assume, there must be a case that in the optimal set of clusters $\mathcal{X}_{1},\dots,\mathcal{X}_{k}$ there could be clusters with elements such that:

$x_{1}, x_{2} \in \mathcal{X}_{i}$, $x_{3}\in \mathcal{X}_{j}$ such that $x_{1} > x_{3}$ and $x_{3}>x_{2}$, i.e. intervals do not necessarily contain consecutive elements of the original sorted set $x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Just because the general problem is NP-hard does not mean the one-dimensional version is also hard. Isn't this solvable with dynamic programming?

Comment: Dear @Michal Adamaszek, I am a bit confused with that. I saw the papers where authors sort the data and then dynamically find a solution with $O(k\times n^{2})$ complexity, but I thought it was just a heuristic approach.

Comment: I think that should work. If you have a clustering which is like in your last paragraph, that is clusters are not contiguous subintervals, then it should pay off to swap the offending points and get a better solution. I have not proved it formally but it feels right. And then the dynamic solution works.

Comment: yes, it feels right, but I  haven't seen proof, neither I proved it myself...

Comment: This problem is NP-Hard only when $d\geq2$. On the real line (1 dimension), not only is it not hard, it even has $O(n\log n)$ algorithms.

Comment: Dear @iarbel84, yes, thank you.